# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I was trying to implement redis with spring Boot, I am randomly encountering below exception on my localhost:

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool;

I have already tried various combinations of properties of the JedisPoolConfig. But none of them are helping not sure where am getting wrong.

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfigurationSetup {    
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(10000);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(1000);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(-1);
        poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(500);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        JedisConnectionFactory ob = new JedisConnectionFactory(poolConfig);
        ob.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        ob.setPort(6379);
        ob.setUsePool(true);
        return ob;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate rt = new RedisTemplate();
        rt.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        rt.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        return rt;
    }
}


public class GeoLocationCacheServiceImpl implements GeoLocationCacheService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("redisTemplate")
    RedisTemplate geoObjectRedisTemplate;

    @Override
    public void saveUpdateGeoLoc(GeoObject geoObject) {

        if (geoObject != null) {
            // Some Business logics 
            geoObjectRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(geoObject.getObjectID(), geoObject);
            // Some Business logics 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post your stacktrace, normally it contains essential information to help you

Comment: facing same issue , am also using spring boot + redis and facing issue randomly

Answer (score 0):

because  rt.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
and From the source code, we can see that

```
if (!enableTransactionSupport) {
            RedisConnectionUtils.releaseConnection(conn, factory);
        }
```